# How to turn a Phaser web game into Facebook instant game?

Tags: facebook, phaser-framework

I made a simple web game using Phaser.io and I now I would like to turn it into a facebook instant game. I've tried following some articles but it didn't work.

Do you know any good source (article, youtube tutorial...) about the process of making a facebook instant game from a web game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To host a Phaser Web Game to Facebook Instant Games, follow these steps:

- First, you need to create a **[new Facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/?advanced_app_create=true)**.
- You will now land on the app dashboard, now you will select **“Settings”**, then **“Basic”**.
- Now in the category select **“Games”**, then choose the category which fits best to your game.
- Back to the dashboard, let’s select **“Instant Games”**.
- Now you have to fill in some information, be sure **“Use Instant Games”** is set to **“Yes”**.
- Now you have to upload a zipped file with the game. You can do this operation under **“Web Hosting”** panel, selecting **“Upload Version”**, 
  then pushing it to production by clicking on the star icon.
- After, you have to include the **Facebook Instant Games API** in your index file:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.6.0.js"&gt;</script>;
```

Then, in your game file, when you normally create the game itself on **`window.onload` function**, you will have to create it this way:

```
FBInstant.initializeAsync().then(function() {
    FBInstant.setLoadingProgress(100);
    FBInstant.startGameAsync().then(function() {
        var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        if(windowWidth &gt; windowHeight){
            windowWidth = windowHeight / 1.8;
        }
        var gameWidth = windowWidth * gameOptions.gameHeight / windowHeight;
        game = new Phaser.Game(gameWidth, gameOptions.gameHeight, Phaser.CANVAS);
        game.state.add("Boot", boot);
        game.state.add("Preload", preload);
        game.state.add("TitleScreen", titleScreen);
        game.state.add("PlayGame", playGame);
        game.state.start("Boot");
    })
})
```

You can check **[this tutorial](https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2018/03/28/how-to-integrate-facebook-instant-games-api-in-your-phaser-game/)** for more details & visual instructions.